# Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed:Invalid value around character 0

Tags: swift

When compile on real device getting this error but there is no problem to compile on simulator.Getting this error FAILURE:

> responseSerializationFailed(reason:
>   Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(error:
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 “Invalid value around
>   character 0.” UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around
>   character 0.}))

Comment: check the response by adding brakepoint. this line...                                     upload.responseJSON { response in

Comment: *Code=3840* means the received data is not JSON.